# Change a private method in java from subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection

Like the title says: is there ANY way to change a private method in Java from a subclass, but only have it affect calls to that subclass?

Lets say class 'X' (which I can edit) extends class 'Y' (which I can't).
Y has a method that references a protected method in another class in the same package, which it can access, since they're in the same package, but X can't, because it's in a different one. It also references multiple private fields.

I want to change a getter referenced in that method, without copying the whole method, fields and reflecting for the protected method.

I can see the source of Y, but I can't edit it.

EDIT: So if I can'y change it, are there any other good solutions to my problem?

Comment: No. Private methods aren't inherited.

Comment: Which means that they also cannot be overridden.

Comment: make the method protected. Then it can be overridden.

Comment: "...but I can't edit it."

Comment: unfortunately for the people who like to tweak the behavior of APIs, the OOP gods have deemed that Thou shalt not use Protected, for verily it might breaketh something in the future.

Comment: You would need to do something dirty like edit code in runtime using agents - but I don't think this is a good solution.